# Saving matplotlib figure with add_axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, jupyter-notebook, axes

I'm trying to save a figure with an extra image on top.
However Python only saves the bottom figure.
I have:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(...)
...

ax_im = fig.add_axes([0.1, 1.0, 1, 1])
ax_im.set_xticks([])
ax_im.set_yticks([])

ax.imshow(...)
...

fig.savefig('image.png')
```

and Matplotlib only saves the figure related to the `ax` axis. In the iPython notebook
the output is fine, it shows both figures, So, I don't know whats happening.

Comment: I found out that `fig.savefig('image.png', bbox_inches='tight')` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
ax_im = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5], label='axes1')
```

The explanation is that your second parameter to `add_axes` is 1.0. This specifies the bottom ot the `Axes` at the top of the figure.

Following example works for me:

```
import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)

ax.plot(range(3))

ax_im = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4])
ax_im.set_xticks([])
ax_im.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

or even easier, use `add_subplot` twice:

```
import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)

ax.plot(range(3))

ax_im = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax_im.plot(range(3), 'o--')
ax_im.set_xticks([])
ax_im.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Comment: But I want the second Figure at top, that's why I specified the second value as `1.0`. If I use `0.2`, the second Figure stays on  the middle of the first one. As I specified, it looks fine on the iPython output :)

Comment: `fig.savefig` only prints the area between 0 and 1. If you want to have the second plot on top, you have to show the first one in the lower part. I updated the example. Here `add_subplot` is called with `212`. The second axis then starts at 0.5 above the first one.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that too, seems a better option. But I found out the solution, which I posted in a comment. Thanks any way :)